# The number of supplied grids is less than the number of variables in formula

Tags: saga

I'm completely new to SAGA. The documentation is really rough with me, and there are not many examples around, so I try to fly by instruments. I tried this:

```
saga_cmd grid_calculus 1 -GRIDS 011x002-corrected.tif -FORMULA 'g1/cos(ypos()*pi()/180)' -RESULT 011x002-adjusted.tif
```

and I get:

```
loading: 011x002-corrected

Grid system: 30.922081; 16385x 16385y; 1676718.907993x 10233337.073165y
Formula: g1/cos(ypos()*pi()/180)
Name: Calculation
Take Formula: false
Use No-Data: false
Data Type: 4 byte floating point number
Grids: 1 object (011x002-corrected)
Grids from different Systems: No objects
Result:

Error: The number of supplied grids is less than the number of variables in formula. (1 < 2)
Error: executing tool [Grid Calculator]
```

I don't understand why it thinks I'm working with two grids. Any ideas?